# I have multiple files in a folder and i want to edit the file names from a specific position using cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

I have multiple files in a folder and I want to edit the file names from a specific position using command prompt in windows 7

File names:

```
32132_213212_5416813135418.txt        >> 32132_ABCXYZ.txt
989545514_545445_1354189313218.txt    >> 989545514_ABCXYZ.txt
32541384_784548_6542314141482.txt     >> 32541384_ABCXYZ.txt
```

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1* delims=_ eol=_" %I in ('dir /B /A:-D "*_*_*.txt"') do @ren "%I_%J" "%I_ABCDEF%~xJ"`

Answer (score 0):

So heres a script which when run INSIDE a folder will rename all .txt files with the first part of the name (upto the first "_") and append to the end "_ABCXYZ" as you specified

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM :: Loop through each file in the current folder
for %%f in (*) do (
    REM :: Get just the file name as the loop returns entire path
    set origName=%%~nxf

    REM :: Check its a .txt file, so we don't rename anything else.
    if !origName:~-4!==.txt (
        REM :: Get everything UP TO the first "_" character
        for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%a in ("!origName!") do set firstPart=%%a

        REM :: Now we can append the string you specified to the end of first past
        set newName=!firstPart!_ABCXYZ.txt

        REM :: Perform the actual rename
        ren !origName! !newName!
        echo RENAMED !origName! TO !newName!
    )
)
pause
```

I've commented it all so you can see what everything does. This could be compacted and not split over so many lines but I kept it verboseso you can see how it functions.

If you'd like a more compact and slightly more efficient one let me know... would be usefull if you're doing millions of files.